# Limit to devices being logged in from a single google account

Tags: google-chrome-extension, authentication, gmail

I need to sync chrome extension data across different devices, but to do that I need to be logged in from the same account in all the devices. So, the number of devices may be up to 20 or so. Is there any restriction on how many devices can be logged in using the same Gmail account at the same time?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: It doesn't need any code or anything. Just plain question is how many devices can we login at the same time using one google account?